# Is stepping on fingernails still a concern today?

Tags: pregnancy-birth, nail-cutting

Rav Chaim Kanievsky is [quoted](https://halachablog.com/2015/01/27/discarding-nail-clippings-according-to-halacha/) saying a pregnant woman  may walk on the nails of a non-Jew.

Does Rav Chaim Kanievsky hold it's still an issue for pregnant women to walk on cut nails today? I recently heard he reportedly said it's not the same issue as it used to be - is there any published source that Rav Chaim Kanievsky said such an idea?

Comment: Seems implicit that he is only addressing those of a non-Jew. Doesn't sound like it has anything to do with these days or earlier days.

Comment: @robev Agreed on the inference. It was really just serving as the introduction to the question of whether Rav Chaim holds something changed today

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Practice of burning or burying fingernail clippings](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56690/practice-of-burning-or-burying-fingernail-clippings) Last two bullets.